# Apache Kafka Consumer Offset

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 1.0.0 and using the following command to check Kafka Offset.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server <<bootstrap server>> --describe --group <<consumergroup>>
```

I will appreciate your feedback on the following Kafka Consumer offset question:

1. If my consumer is down , how can I check the consumer offset? since
   the above command display the following message:

   `Consumer group <<consumer group>> does not exist or is re-balancing`
2. How can I reset the Consumer Offset , When my consumer is down ?